# Making a variable value constant in swift

Tags: ios, swift, constants

I'm very new to coding in swift, so I barely know any of the syntaxes.
I am defining a variable in view controller and assigning it a random 4 digit value.
I want to assign this value only once, when the app is installed/updated, and not every time the user opens the app.
Help me out if any of you know a fix for this. The following is my current code

```
import UIKit
let stranger = String(arc4random_uniform(10000))

class ViewController: UIViewController {...}
```

Comment: Save the value into user defaults with unique key. access the value by giving unique key from user defaults.

Comment: userDefaults is a great way to store data easily in non volatile memory, but you might want to check keychain if the value you want to store is secret/private. UserDefaults is not secured and can easily be read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `UserDefaults` for save your random value. When you open you app first time then you will be got some random value in **stranger**. Add those value in `UserDefaults` with specific **key** and you can access value by use of **key** that you set in `UserDefault`.

**Ex.**

You get random value **1234** in **stranger** then you should first check you already set the value or not?

```
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "keyRandom") == nil { // If value already set then you do not need to reset
  UserDefaults.standard.set(stranger, forKey: "keyRandom")
}
```

And if you want to access value you can get it by

```
print("\(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "keyRandom") ?? "not Found")")
```

Comment: Don’t use value for key and don’t force unwrap. Your App will crash if that value hasn’t being set. Also UserDefaults has a specific method to retrieve a String from it called string(forKey:) among other types. It also has a method to register default values into it as shown in the answer below.

Comment: Don’t use setValue use set(Any:, forKey:) and again don’t use value(forKey:) use string(forKey:) or object(forKey:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data in a persistent data store if you want to persist between launches. `UserDefaults` is a simple solution, and you can use the `registerDefaults` method to seed it.

Register your default properties. In `AppDelegate.didFinishingLaunching` may be a good place

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
            "MyKey" : String(arc4random_uniform(10000))
        ])
```

Pull out the value:

```
let stranger = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "MyKey")
```

If you don't want to register the defaults on app start, or need to change it, then you can also set the property when you first need it, using an `if let` check to see if it already exists, and if not, set it.

```
func getStranger() -> String {
    if let v = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "MyKey") {
        return v
    } else {
        let rand = String(arc4random_uniform(10000))
        UserDefaults.standard.set(rand, forKey:"MyKey")
        return rand
    }
}
```

*Note: Code written in SO answer box, not tested and may contain syntax errors. Demo purposes only*